# Player sprite not displaying in window

Tags: c++, sfml

I've been trying to create a sprite in visual studio using sfml and c++, the code itself is running fine and there appear to be no errors.

PLAYER.H

```
#pragma once
#include "pSprite.h"
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include <Windows.h>

class Player : public pSprite
{
public:
Input input;
Player(const sf::Vector2f & size = sf::Vector2f(0, 0));
~Player();

pSprite playerSprite;
sf::Texture texture;

float playerWidth;
float playerHeight;
float playerSpeed;

void update(float dt);
void initPlayer(float x, float y);
void kill(); // set to gameover
bool isAlive();
void move();

sf::Vector2f position;
```

Here is the header file for the Player class which is derived from a pSprite class which itself is derived from a Sprite class in order to get around the "Cannot instantiate abstract class" error.

PLAYER.CPP

```
void Player::initPlayer(float x, float y)
{
position.x = x;
position.y = y;

playerWidth = 60;
playerHeight = 50;

texture.loadFromFile("player1.png");
playerSprite.setTexture(&texture);
playerSprite.setSize(sf::Vector2f(playerWidth, playerHeight));

playerSpeed = 10;

playerSprite.setPosition(position);
}
```

Here is the code for the function which loads the texture and should set the sprite.

initPlayer is called in the main function and should set it up ready for all other functions called in the main and for drawing and displaying.

Comment: What is your player initial x and y?

Comment: Post the code as text not pictures of code. Thx.

Comment: Also, you do know that you need to explicitly [draw](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-sprite.php#ok-can-i-have-my-sprite-now) the sprite at every frame?

Comment: @litelite yes and that is what should be happening in the main, and the initial x and y are (400, 500) and the window is (800, 600)

Comment: So in your main you are calling something like `player.playerSprite.draw` ?

Comment: "Here is the header file for the Player class which is derived from a pSprite class which itself is derived from a Sprite class in order to get around the "Cannot instantiate abstract class" error." makes right around no amount of sense. Anyways, have you double checked to make sure the image is actually being loaded?

Comment: And why is the player itself is a sprite when it already contains a sprite!

Comment: @George yeah i've just double checked again and it is apparently loading

Comment: @litelite the main is calling 'window.draw(player)' which according to everyone else i've checked with SHOULD do it right, and im not certain what you mean exactly

Comment: Your sprite is loaded in `playerSprite` not the player itself (which is the one you are drawing). Right now, your player have nothing to draw. As a quick fix, you could just do away with `playerSprite` and call all the methods that you used to call on `playerSprite` directly on the player.

Comment: @litelite holy shit that now makes perfect sense thank you so much thats fixed it!!! i am a fool